# What is best practice to scale multiple Elastic Beats to centralized Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

My goal is to view the logs of more than 100 machines connected to a centralized Logstash instance with the output to a Elasticsearch cluster, starting with 5 machines.

What is the best practice to scale this sort of application or is there any good article to read about or are there any examples?

I've done a lot of research about this and the only things I found is to horizontal scale every instance:

- Scale Logstash
- Scale Elasticsearch

But I think there is a lot more to think about.

Other ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can check this post from elastic forum which speaks on 40 machines but i guess it isn't make that of a different because you can just run another `logstash` service on the centralize machine when both of them will point to the same `elastic` cluster https://community.bitnami.com/t/setup-and-configure-elk-on-aws-to-monitor-multiple-ec2-instances/58900/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It heavily depends on the parsing each of your logstash instances has to do. 
I am collecting for example apache logs from 100+ machines with only one logstash instance which runs on a node of the elk cluster without any problems. Grok Parsing tends to take up alot of resources. So i would do the following:

- Install one Logstash instance
- Slowly add clients and monitor the performance of the system
- As soon as you hit your own threshold, add another logstash instance.

Voilá! :)